# Defining database options for Joomla framework package

Tags: database, joomla-framework

I'm using the Joomla Database Framework package for an internal project.

To initiate a Database instance, I'm using the following:

```
$db = Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver::getInstance($options);
```

The `$options` variable would look something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'XXXXX',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'database' => 'XXXXX',
);
```

Any function that has a database query will require the `getInstance` which is perfect fine, however I do not wish to define the `$options` in every single function.

How would I overcome this?

Would it be better to create a wrapper class/function and call that instead?

Comment: Better to use wrapper class as you already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper class and function as per the below:

```
class Database
{
    protected $db;

    private function _connect()
    {  
        $dbFactory = new Joomla\Database\DatabaseFactory;

        try
        {
            $this->db = $dbFactory->getDriver(
                'mysqli',
                array(
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'user'      => 'XXXXX',
                    'password'  => 'XXXXX',
                    'database'  => 'XXXXX',
                    'prefix'    => 'jos_'
                )
            );
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
        }

        return $this->db;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        return $this->_connect();
    }
}
```

And then in any function where I was to call this, I use:

```
$dbo    = new Database;
$db     = $dbo->connect();
```